# How do I align an element on the edge of a container and keep the text aligned and not overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a container that has a small label on the top right edge (like the green `span` of the code below), and I don't want it to cover the text. The text must be vertically centered.

Using `position: absolute` the text is covered, using `float: right` I couldn't align the text in the center. How can I do this?

Here are my attempts:

1. Using `position: absolute`

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <span class="sub-item-1"></span>
    <span class="sub-item-2">Centered text</span>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <span class="sub-item-1"></span>
    <span class="sub-item-2">Centered text one two three four five six seven</span>
 </div>
</div>

<style>
  .container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start; 
  }

  .item-1 {
    height: 40px;
    min-width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    align-self: center;
  }

  .item-2 {
    width: 100%;
    align-self: center;
  }

  .sub-item-1 {
    height: 10px;
    min-width: 35px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
</style>
```

2. Using `float: right`

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <span class="sub-item-1"></span>
    <span class="sub-item-2">Centered text</span>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <span class="sub-item-1"></span>
    <span class="sub-item-2">Centered text one two three four five six seven</span>
 </div>
</div>

<style>
  .container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start; 
  }

  .item-1 {
    height: 40px;
    min-width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    align-self: center;
  }

  .item-2 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .sub-item-1 {
    height: 10px;
    min-width: 35px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    float:right;

  }
</style>
```

Comment: You want to align the text to center?

Comment: @AmirrezaAmini Yes.

Comment: use ``text-align: center;``.

Comment: @AmirrezaAmini This does not center vertically..

Answer (score 0):

Here, float is content sensitive & absolute positioning is not.

(must go with float if you can text under it)

and your inline element can't be full height (because filled height inline element can't centre it's content vertically)

So, you can use `line-height: 50px;` to sub-item-2 if it's one line text.

Comment: `sub-item-2` can have one or more lines, so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will solve your issue mostly -

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <span class="sub-item-1"></span>
    <span class="sub-item-2">Centered text</span>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <span class="sub-item-1"></span>
    <span class="sub-item-2">Centered text one two three four five six seven</span>
 </div>
</div>

<style>
  .container {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start; 
  }

  .item-1 {
    height: 40px;
    min-width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    align-self: center;
  }

  .item-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .sub-item-1 {
    height: 10px;
    min-width: 35px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    float:right;

  }
  .sub-item-2 {
    margin: auto 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .sub-item-2:after {
    content:"";
   width: 1px;
   display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Your code has a problem because the text is coming out of the container, and it should remain fully visible inside it. I changing the `height:50px` to `min-heigth:50px` so that this doesn't happen anymore, but even so your solution doesn't vertically center the text.